# Configure Root-Path of WebApplication

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, struts, tiles

i'm struggling with configuring the root-path of my WebApplication.
I'm developing with Struts2 on TomCat7-Server. My structure in Eclipse is the following image:

http://schlangguru.de.vu/tmp/Auswahl_006.jpg

In my struts and tiles config files, i can access my resources by entering an absolute path like "/pv/common/css/style.css" but in my jsp-files i have to enter "/pv-jetzendorf_4.0/pv/common/css/style.css" as an absolute path. How can i configure the root-path for all elements to be "/pv/..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring the root path is not the appropriate fix for your problem. The application should work whatever the root path is. Simply use the JSTL `<c:url>` tag or the struts  tag to generate your URLs:

```
<link href="<c:url value='/pv/common/css/style.css'/>" .../>
```